# Data in view doesn't load if id is passed to controller in anchor tag to perform certain action

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I want to pass a id through anchor tag to controller. get data from controller and bind it in another view. ID passes to controller successfully and saledetailsitems array gets data but data doesnt bind to the next view...

**This is my 1st view**

```
<tbody id=Tabledata>

     <tr ng-repeat="item in saleitems">
       <td>{{item.id}}</td>
       <td>{{item.totalqnty}}</td>
       <td>{{item.totalprice}}</td>
      <td><a ng-href="#/saledetailstable" ng-click="getsaledetailstabledata('{{item.inv_no}}')">{{item.inv_no}}</a></td>
       <td>{{item.inv_date}}</td>
       <td>{{item.sync_status}}</td>
       <td>{{item.device_Id}}</td>
       <td>{{item.U_id}}</td>
     </tr>
```

**This is my controller**

```
$scope.getsaledetailstabledata=function(id){
  var divapend=angular.element( document.querySelector( '#Tabledatadetails' ) );

  var query = "SELECT * FROM SALE_DETAILS WHERE inv_no=?";
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query,[id]).then(function(res){
   for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++){
    $scope.saledetailsitems.push({"id":res.rows.item(i).id,"inv_no":res.rows.item(i).inv_no,"itemcode":res.rows.item(i).itemcode,"price":res.rows.item(i).price,"qnty":res.rows.item(i).qnty,"total_price":res.rows.item(i).total_price,"sync_status":res.rows.item(i).sync_status});

    alert("got details!");

  }

},function(err){
  console.error(err);
});
```

**This is my next view**

```
<tbody>

     <tr ng-repeat="item in saledetailsitems">
       <td>{{item.id}}</td>
       <td>{{item.inv_no}}</td>
       <td>{{item.itemcode}}</td>
      <td>{{item.price}}</td>
       <td>{{item.qnty}}</td>
       <td>{{item.total_price}}</td>
       <td>{{item.sync_status}}</td>
     </tr> 

   </tbody>
```

Comment: To find the index of an object in an array use $index inside ng-click function and also in your controller function in order to access the particular object. For example: **ng-click="array($index)";** and in your controller **$scope.array=function($index){ console.log($index);};**

Comment: i am able to get the clicked id and that calls the function in controller successfully but when the view changes ('next view') in ng repeat that doesnt shows up the data..

Comment: Whether both views are using the same controller??

Comment: yes...both are using same controller..

Comment: Check whether $scope.saledetailsitems contains the required data with in the controller after the loop

Comment: yes $scope.saledetailsitems gets all the data after the loop.and the view changes. it also gets  alert("got details!"); but in view page i dont get the data..

Comment: do i need to set some model...??

Comment: @JackyCoogan  I tried every possible way but the data is not showing..